# Why don't engineers put tesla valves in the airboxes of carbureted internal combustion engines?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

**Before I ask the full question, I want to quickly cover two common issues that come up in high performance engine design.**

1. When intake valves close in an engine a small shockwave moves backwards through the carburetor into the air intake. At higher RPM, this shockwave becomes stronger and can cause the air intake volume to resonate causing a low pressure state when the engine valves reopen. Less charge is delivered to the combustion chamber causing a loss of power. This is referred to as [fuel standoff](https://www.enginelabs.com/news/engine-theory-quick-fuel-standoff/) and it normally becomes an issue at higher RPM and high load.
2. When an engine starts running at higher RPM, the amount of time that valves are open for becomes shorter making it more difficult to deliver a greater charge to the cylinder. Normally cam timing is set with some [valve overlap](https://help.summitracing.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4703/%7E/what-is-valve-overlap%3F#:%7E:text=Overlap%20is%20when%20the%20intake,beginning%20of%20the%20intake%20stroke.) to help mitigate this issue with some success.

There's a way to use the first problem as an additional solution to the second problem. If an airbox is tuned to the right resonant frequency, the airbox will be in a high pressure state when intake valves open at higher RPM. Since this is where valve intervals become short, it allows for more charge to be forced through the carburetor into the cylinder making up for the power loss.

I found some research on [Numerical Simulation and Hydrodynamic Design Optimization of a Tesla-Type Valve for Micropumps](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266574843_Numerical_Simulation_and_Hydrodynamic_Design_Optimization_of_a_Tesla-Type_Valve_for_Micropumps) and couldn't help but wonder why I've never seen a design like this in an airbox. If it's easier for air to enter a Tesla valve than it is to escape, wouldn't some of the energy resulting from the intake valves closing get trapped in the airbox, increasing airbox pressure at a wider RPM range instead of just at high RPM? I'm having trouble applying [helmholtz resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_resonance) equations to this Tesla type valve because the functional length of the tube is shorter in one direction than it is in the other.

Is there a set of equations better suited to analyze this problem?

Comment: Turbos are used to get more air in at higher rpm.

Comment: There's two questions in there, and the more itneresting one IMo is the one near the end: "Is there a set of equations better suited than Helmholtz resonance to this problem?" Is this the question you want to focus on, or the one in the title?

Comment: @SolarMike, absolutely turbos are a great option. There aren't a whole lot of carbureted cars out there anymore. I'm more thinking about this in terms of motorcycle engine design. I definitely should have specified that in the body of the question, but I didn't want to eliminate insights from car engine design. I don't see a lot of turbo charged motorcycles out there but there are a few.

Comment: @mart If there's a good reason to not do this then it would be good to know before I start modeling and 3D printing. If there isn't a good reason, then it would definitely help to have a better set of equations than Helmholtz's work. I'm trying to avoid using 3D fluid simulation software if I can get a rough idea of airbox and airbox snorkel geometry to iterate on. The differing lengths of airflow paths is really tripping me up and if I can get even a rough idea of how the resonant properties will change after even a few reverberations that would help a lot.